# Receiving ByteArrayResource( from java) into Blob (into javascript)

Tags: javascript, java, blob

any help to my problem would be really appreciated.
Here is the context:

I am currently sending a zip file from java RestControler:

```
public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(@RequestBody ProjectDTO projectDTO) {
    Project project = ProjectDTO.toProject(projectDTO);
    byte[] out = initApplicationService.download(project);
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(out);
    return ResponseEntity
      .ok()
      .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + getZipFilename(project))
      .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
      .contentLength(out.length)
      .header("X-Suggested-Filename", getZipFilename(project))
      .body(resource);
  }
```

This works really well because i can dowload it through swagger.

But on plain javascript front, i can't figure out what i am missing :
primary:

```
const download = async (): Promise<void> => {
      if (project.value.folder !== '') {
        await projectService
          .download(toProject(project.value))
          .then(response => {
              const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response],{type:'application/octet-stream'}));
              const link = document.createElement('a');
              link.href = url;
              link.setAttribute('download', project.value.baseName + '.zip');
              document.body.appendChild(link);
              link.click();
          })
          .catch(error => logger.error('Downloading project failed', error));
      }
    };
```

calling secondary:

```
async download(project: Project): Promise<ArrayBuffer> {
    const restProject: RestProject = toRestProject(project);
    return this.axiosHttp
      .post<ArrayBuffer, RestProject>('api/projects/download', restProject)
      .then(response => new Uint8Array(response.data));
  }
```

It dowloads well a zip but well opening it i got the following error :
"An error occured during archive loading"
Thanks to any help :)

Answer (score 1):

I added the responseType in post request and i also removed Uint8Array convertion and it worked fine.

```
return this.axiosHttp
      .post<ArrayBuffer,RestProject>('api/projects/download', restProject,{ responseType: 'blob' })
      .then(response => response.data);
```

I guess that when receiving the datas, axios needs to know what is coming to convert correctly it in the proper format. on the fly.